# why when we write \n in the file it converts into \r\n combination?

Tags: c, newline, fgets, fputs

I read this concept from book that when we attemp to write \n to the file using fputs(), fputs() converts the \n to \r\n combination and then if we read the same line back using fgets () the reverse conversion happens means \r\n back convert to \n.
I don't get that what is the purpose behind this?

Comment: One of the characters is a "line feed", the other is a "carriage return"; terms dating back to the days of line printers. Both characters were necessary because individually, the line feed would move the paper by one line without changing the column, while the carriage return would change to the leftmost column without changing the line.

Comment: I understand the issue, but I don't believe the statement is true. For example, if you write a file with a single '\n', that file has a length of one. Maybe in some windows world what the book says is true, but not in the normal unix world.

Answer (score 3):

It is because Windows (and MS-DOS) text files are supposed to have lines ending in \r\n, and portable C programs are supposed to simply use \n because C was originally defined on Unix.

And it's not just fputs and fgets that do it - any I/O function on a text file, even getc and fread, will do the same conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Succinctly, DOS is the reason for this.

Different systems have different conventions for line endings.  Unix reckons one character, `'\n'`, is sufficient to mark the end of a line.  DOS decided that it needed two characters, `'\r'` and `'\n'`, though other systems also used that convention.  The versions of Mac OS 1-9 (prior to Mac OS X) used just `'\r'` instead. Other systems could use a count and the line data instead of a line ending, or could simulate punched cards with blanks up to a fixed length (72 or 80). Unix also doesn't distinguish between binary and text files; DOS does.  (DOS also uses <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> to mark EOF in a text file. Unix doesn't have an EOF marker; it knows exactly how big the file is and uses that length to determine when it has reached EOF.)

C originate on Unix, but to make it easier to migrate code between the systems, the standard I/O package defined that when it was working on text files, the input side would convert a native line ending to the single `'\n'` character for uniform input, and the output side would convert a `'\n'` to the native line ending.

However, the mention of text files also meant that there needed to be binary files, where these mappings do not occur.

You might note that most of the internet protocols (HTTP, for example) mandate CRLF (carriage return, line feed, or `'\r'`, `'\n'`) for the end of line markers.

(Actually, blaming DOS, as in MS-DOS or PC-DOS, is a little unfair.  There were other systems that used the CRLF line end convention before DOS existed, and they may have been more influential on the Internet. However, almost all those ancestral systems are substantially defunct, and Windows is the environment that you'll run into these days where the distinction between binary and text files matters, and where you'll encounter CRLF line endings.)

Note that the C standard has this to say about text files:

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.2 Files

> ¶2 A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
>   consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
>   last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters
>   may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing
>   conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data
>   that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing
>   characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is
>   immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character.
>   Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character
>   appear when read in is implementation-defined.

That's a lot of things that might or might not happen.  Note, in particular, that trailing blanks written to a file might, or might not, appear in the input — according to the standard.  That allows the systems that support punched card images or fixed length records to comply with the standard.

Note, too (as pointed out by [Giacomo Degli Eposti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20796/giacomo-degli-esposti)), that this all means that if you open a file in binary mode that was originally written as a text file, you may very well get a significantly different list of bytes back from the I/O system.  You'll see two characters per newline; you might see a <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> followed by other characters (possibly null bytes) up to a 'block' boundary that might be a multiple of 256 bytes, etc.

Comment: And note also that if, on a Windows box, you write on a file in "text mode" and reopen the same file in "binary mode" you will read two distinct characters (i.e. you read the bytes actually written on the file)

Comment: So a main() { printf("\n") } in this environment results in a file of size 2? Weird. But the stdio is smart enough that it mostly goes away even between environments?

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Yes, because a text file with one empty line has a size of 2 bytes.

Comment: `\n` and `\r\n` are not the only end-of-line representations. MacOS before OSX used `\r`. Other systems don't necessarily use a character sequence to denote the end of a line; they might use some kind of record structure (VAX/VMS, IBM mainframes, etc).

Comment: @Jonathan how did you enter the Control-Z glyph(s) that make it appear like a key?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil: As `<kbd>Control-Z</kbd>`, noting that the notation does not work in comments.  You could attempt to edit the answer to see the notation and then cancel your edit when you've found out what you want to know.

Comment: you know whats funny i worked this out a few days ago using Inspect Element in browser on a different forum (vuo.org). then I just saw your answer now :-) Thx.