# Error with binary-writting mode with C, on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, apache

I am learning how to write a simple CGI page with C language. I tried with Apache on both Linux and Windows. I compiled my scripts on 2 different computers that run different OSes.

---

1. Firstly, I created a simple CGI page for getting a static plain-text content:

```
    #include 

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("plain_text.txt", "r"); // text-mode only.

        if (fp)
        {
            int ch;

            printf("content-type: text/plain\n\n");

            while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I compiled it into an executable and put it in `cgi-bin` directory. When I browse it with my web-browser, it returns the plain-text content correctly (both Linux and Windows).

---

2. Then, I modified above script for getting a simple JPEG content.
   (I understand that: every JPEG picture is a binary file)

```
   #include 

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("cat_original.jpg", "rb"); // with binary-mode.

        if (fp)
        {
            int ch;

            printf("content-type: image/jpg\n\n");

            while (((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) || (!feof(f1))) // can read whole content of any binary file.
            {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I compiled it into an executable and put it in `cgi-bin` directory, too.
I can get the correct returned-image with Linux compiled-executable files; but, the Windows does not.

---

To understand the problem, I downloaded the returned-image with Windows compiled-execute files.
(I named this image: `cat_downloaded_windows.jpg`)
Then, I used VBinDiff for compare 2 images: `cat_original.jpg` (68,603 bytes) and `cat_downloaded_windows.jpg` (68,871 bytes).
There are many lines in `cat_downloaded_windows.jpg` (like the row I marked) have a character which `cat_original.jpg` does not have.

[VBinDiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwAus.jpg)

So, I guess that the Windows OS causes the problem (Windows add some characters automatically, and Linux does not)
(Apache and web-browsers do not cause problem)

---

So, I posted this topic into StackOverflow for getting your helps. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any problem with the `printf("%c", ch);` (in my script) on Windows?
2. Is there any way to print binary content into `stdout`, both Linux and Windows?

I am learning programming myself, and this is the first time I ask on StakOverflow.
So, if my question is not clear, please comment below this question; I will try to explain it more.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is the size of `cat_downloaded_linux` 68,603 bytes? (i,e same as `cat_original.jpg`)

Comment: Type of `ch` should be `int`

Comment: Why? Just let Aoache serve the actual file itself. Your CGI is adding no value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `printf()` to write to standard output, it is working in text mode, not binary mode, so every time your program encounters a newline `\n` in the JPEG file, it writes `\r\n` on Windows, which corrupts the JPEG file.

You'll need to know how to put standard output into binary mode and you'll need to ensure that you generate `\r\n` in place of `\n` in the headers.

The MSDN documentation says you can use [`_setmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx), and shows an example (setting `stdin` instead of `stdout`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(void)  
{  
    int result;  

    // Set "stdin" to have binary mode:  
    result = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);  
    if (result == -1)
        perror("Cannot set mode");  
    else  
        printf("'stdin' successfully changed to binary mode\n");  
}
```

Comment: `_setmode` is not a standard library function.

Comment: @t2533799: No, of course `_setmode()` isn't standard as defined by ISO 9899 or POSIX.  It's a Microsoft function needed to make things work on Microsoft's Windows.  But that's the platform where the OP has a problem, so it is appropriate to offer the help there.

Comment: Yes, `_setmode` is very useful. But, is there alternative way to solve my problem?

Comment: I dunno; you'll have to wait for someone else to proffer an alternative solution.  I don't know of another way of dealing with binary files written to standard output on Windows.  You might find something on a site like — oh, maybe Stack Overflow.  I've not tried searching for duplicates yet.

Comment: Searching SO with '`[c] binary standard output windows`' throws up some candidates: [Portable way to put stdout in binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609260/)—[Why when we write \n in the file it converts into \r\n combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839883/)—[Is it possible to pass binary data through the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554252/)—[Simple encryption/decryption algorithm causing EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781430/). You may want to follow some of the links from some of the answers to at least some of those questions.

Comment: I upvoted, but I think it needs to be clarified that this is the behavior of Microsoft C/C++ on Windows, which specifically implements text mode in its low-level POSIX emulation layer. The Windows I/O system has no notion of text mode. It's all just bytes to the OS.